# How to replace all values in row 1 that are less than or equal to 10 with a value of 10 in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I don't know how to replace all values in row 1 that are less than or equal to 10 with the value 10 in a data frame
For example.

```
mtcars 
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 ... 
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 ... 
Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 ...
```

I want to replace row 1 Mazda RX4 values less than or equal to 10 to be replaced with a 10 to end up showing up like this

```
               mpg cyl disp  hp drat wt ... 
Mazda RX4     21.0   10  160 110 10  10 ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

We can create a logical vector based on the 1st row and assign the values that are TRUE for the 1st row to 10

```
mtcars[1,][mtcars[1,] <= 10] <- 10
mtcars[1,]
#          mpg cyl disp  hp drat wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4  21  10  160 110   10 10 16.46 10 10   10   10
```